# En-lighting math puzzle

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

1 + 1 =1

2 + 6 =8

3 + 1 =3

4 + 5 =9

5 + 5 =5

6 + 0 =8

7 + 8 =8

8 - 1 =E

> Hint : FWW

Comment: Is 1+1=0 definitely correct? This one seems not to fit the pattern of all the others (to me)...

Comment: @Stiv i don't know how i made that mistake .. :)

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I know @Stiv has it!

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis I do, but I've been pretty sure it's a duplicate - [and I've just found it](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44346/this-calculator-is-messed-up)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is

> what you get on a 7-segment display if you overlay each of the things on the left (any segments that are turned on in either of the left-hand-side characters is turned on in the right-hand-side character).

As for the last one,

> subtraction turns the segments off.